# Zend, Ajax/Jquery and Progressive Enhancement

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery

I have been using PHP/Zend for quite a while and now I need to start using AJAX
to improve our overall user experience. I am currently working on being able to display a modal window (a box) in the middle of a page where I will display some dynamic information to the user (this "info" is actually a number of small pages displayed in the box, sometimes a form, warnings, messages, advertizing...). I am trying to scope the biggest number of browsers/versions and possibles.

Would you guys agree that first I should have all the info (pages) I need to display divided in different actions/controllers and only them use AJAX to pull this info in a modal box so that I could scope this situation? I mean so that users without fancy browser could still navigate?

I am pretty sure that's something everybody faces on a daily basis. How do you guys deal with this?

Comment: Pretty much like u pointed out. Everything i need is an action. Look up "contextSwitch" or "actionContext" for Zend - no need to render the whole html structure if you only want the body ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you have to just print different content, you can use one controller ("box") and one action (said "view"). Besides, I would like to have a little database of those content and so you can use the same controller/action and give different content just changing a parameter. In this way, as you want, you can serve them in a lot of different way (for example for the "fancy" browser). I hope this could help.